# Using an XOR cipher to encrypt my IM message streams

Tags: javascript, php, encryption

I am looking to create an instant messenger using JS and PHP for my final year project at university.

I am yet to start implementing it but I want to know how I would use a simple encryption technique to encrypt the streams of data send form user to user.

I am looking to use an XOR cipher to do this but I am not sure where to start. Can someone please help me with some suggestions into what language I would use, how I would apply it to my IM, and basically where to start as I am very new to this?

Thanks!!

Comment: The problem with this question is that it's rather broad and also slightly opinion-based. If you could split your question into more specific, smaller questions then it might be more suitable.

Comment: Since you are using JS and PHP, there will be no direct sending user-to-user, but your server will be in between. So use SSL, and you’re fine. (_Storing_ messages on your server in an encrypted format would be a whole different question.)

Answer (score 2):

Generally you would split messages apart into blocks of the same size as your key, and then cipher those. However, you shouldn't just XOR directly (XOR'ing every block with the same key) - see the [Stream Cipher Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher_attack).

Better would be using a your block cipher in "Counter Mode" where you add a number every time to prevent that sort of attack: [Block Cipher / Counter Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29).

Better again would be to use a quality block cipher like AES. It's not that hard!

Comment: Welcome to the crypto dungeons of stackoverflow, Murph :)

Comment: Thanks! Posting under crypto always makes me a little nervous - there's almost always a more correct answer to be written, but it's tough choosing the right level of depth to go into.